# Django - Serving production using Apache2

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, python-3.10

Days I struggle with this.

I have a django webapp written in Python 3.10 that works fine when launched using `pipenv shell` then `python3.10 manage.py runserver`. Also, doing `python3.10 app/wsgi.py` quits without any error.

Now I want it to be served by Apache2.
Here is my conf file:

```
Listen 8000
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /opt/app

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    LogLevel Debug

    Alias /static /opt/app/static
    <Directory /opt/app/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /opt/app/app>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/app/app/wsgi.py

    WSGIDaemonProcess app python-home=/opt/app python-path=/opt/app/app:/usr/local/lib/python3.10:/usr/local/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages

    WSGIProcessGroup app
</VirtualHost>
```

Results in HTTP 500 when navigating to my website.

Apache2 error logs:

```
[core:notice] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[wsgi:info] mod_wsgi (pid=25232): Attach interpreter ''.
[wsgi:info] mod_wsgi (pid=25232): Adding '/opt/app/app' to path.
[wsgi:info] mod_wsgi (pid=25232): Adding '/usr/local/lib/python3.10' to path.
[wsgi:info] mod_wsgi (pid=25232): Adding '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload' to path.
[wsgi:info] mod_wsgi (pid=25232): Adding '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages' to path.
[wsgi:info] [remote 192.168.3.110:37296] mod_wsgi (pid=25232, process='app', application=''): Loading Python script file '/opt/app/app/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] [remote 192.168.3.110:37296] mod_wsgi (pid=25232): Failed to exec Python script file '/opt/app/app/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] [remote 192.168.3.110:37296] mod_wsgi (pid=25232): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/app/app/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error]   File "/opt/app/app/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[wsgi:error]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[wsgi:error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[wsgi:error]     from django.utils.version import get_version
[wsgi:error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 1, in <module>
[wsgi:error]     import datetime
[wsgi:error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/datetime.py", line 1185
[wsgi:error]     def __new__(cls, year, week, weekday, /):
[wsgi:error]                                           ^
[wsgi:error] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Content of my wsgi.py file :

```
import sys
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/opt/app')
sys.path.append('/opt/app/app')

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'vpo.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The python parameter syntax with "/"

```
def __new__(cls, year, week, weekday, /):
```

is new since Python 3.8:
https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters

You need to use the same python version to compile mod_wsgi for Apache that you use in the virt.environment. Please post the message that you get in error.log when you start Apache. Most certainly it is not Python 3.10.

update:

1. First Possibility:

this is the way I installed mod_wsgi with Python3.10 on Ubuntu:

```
$ cd /var/www/django_project/
$ python3.10 -m venv env
$ source env/bin/activate
$ pip install mod_wsgi              # this installed automatically the right version
$ mod_wsgi-express module-config    # console output to be added to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   
   LoadModule wsgi_module "/var/www/django_project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py310.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
   WSGIPythonHome "/var/www/django_project/env"
```

so far Apache is running well in dev environment! I never tried that in production with Python 3.10

2. Second Possibility: Check if you really need Python 3.10 for your project.

Comment: Yes indeed, by default mod_wsgi is compiled with Python 3.7 and seems to be it is not possible to compile it using Python 3.10 (see: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/687) so I'm totally lost.